# How to save the edited table data in CSV file in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-table, export-to-csv

I am currently having issues with save the table data in data.csv file. Using this javascript I am getting the value from table and show it in alert box, but I want to store this variable data in adata.csv file. I have passed the hidden field value into this page. Please edit my code, because this is my first PHP code.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
        function GetCellValues()
        {
            var str = '';
            var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
            var table=document.getElementById("project");
            for (var i=0;i<table.rows[0].cells.length;i++)
            {
                if (i > 2 )
                {
                    str = str + table.rows[0].cells[3].innerHTML.replace(", ");
                }
                else
                {
                    str = str + (table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML) + ', ' ;
                }
            }
        for (var c = 1 ; c < rows.length ; c++)
        {
            str += '\n' + "0" + c + ', ';
            var row = rows[c];
            var inputs = row.getElementsByTagName('input');                
            for (var k = 0 ; k < inputs.length ; k++)
            if (k > 1)
            {
                str += inputs[k].value.replace(", ");
            }
            else 
            {
                str += inputs[k].value + ', ';
            }
        }   
        document.getElementById('hiden').value = str;
        alert(document.getElementById('hiden').value);
    }
```

Here I have the problem, I am not able to save the table data into the file.

```
    <?php
        function saved()
        {
            $handle = fopen("data.csv", "w");
            $hiden = $_REQUEST["hiden"];
            fwrite($handle,$hiden);
        }
    ?>
    </script>       
    </head>
```

I have made the buttons in the following way:

```
    <body>
    <form>
        <br>
        <h1 style="text-align: center">* * * PROJECTS * * *</h1>
        <br>
            <input type = "hidden" id = "hiden" name = "hiden" value = "">
            <input type = "button" name = "submit" onclick = "GetCellValues()" Value = "SAVE">
            <input type = "button" name = "submit" onclick = "document.write('<?php echo saved() ?>');"  Value = "submit"> 

        <br>
    </form>
```

Here I stored the data from .csv file and display it in table:

```
    <?php
        $handle = fopen("data.csv", "w");
        $hide = $_REQUEST['hide'];
        fwrite($handle,$hide);

        $file = file('data.csv');
        $lines = count($file);

        echo'<table id = "project" border = "1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0"
        style = "width: 60%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; border-color: brown; background-color:gray;">';
        echo'<tr cellpadding="100">
            <th width="15%">Sl.No.</th>
            <th width="15%">Project Name</th>
            <th width="15%">ChangeDate</th>
            <th width="15%">Changed By</th>
        </tr>';
        for ($i=1; $i<$lines; $i++) 
        {
            $part = explode(',', $file[$i]);
            echo'<tr>
                <td align= "center" width="5%">'.$part[0].'</td>
                <td align= "center" width="25%"><input type="text" value='.$part[1].'></td>
                <td align= "center" width="25%"><input type="text" value='.$part[2].'></td>
                <td align= "center" width="25%"><input type="text" value='.$part[3].'></td> 
            </tr>';
        }
        echo'</table>'; 
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's fputcsv() function

Check:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_fputcsv.asp
http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: Yes u r write but here it is the dynamic table and I want to store the data in csv fle... Already I am getting the data and stored it in hidden field but I want to know only thing is how to store ther hidden field data in a file...@user1972507

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax to send the string generated to your php file and from there you can write to csv file. 
For writing easy javascript use [jquery](http://jquery.com/).

Other thing you can do is, once you have data in hidden variable "submit" the form. `document.forms['user'].submit();`

Comment: I am not able to submit the form because this is the php page.I don't know how to pass the hidden field value. @ goutham2027